# Internal Erro 500 when using class in symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I am really new to symfony but a long year developer. Now I decided to look at symfony but as it is with new things, problems aint far :)

I want to include a class into my project. Everytime I create a instanec of the class

```
$fw = new FloydWarshall($graph, $nodes);
```

i'll receive an **internal error 500**.

What am I doing wrong ?

Structure:

```
app/
  ...
bin/
  ...
src/AppBundle/
       Controller/MyController.php
       Entity/
           ...
       Model/
          fw.class.php
       Reposetory/
               ...
var/
  ...
vendor/
   ...
web/
  ...
```

So in my class the namespace looks like

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\lpNodes;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use AppBundle\Model\FloydWarshall;
....
```

In my fw.class.php the header looks like:

```
<?php

/**
* @package FloydWarshall
* @author Janne Mikkonen <janne dot mikkonen at julmajanne dot com>
* @date $Date: 2013/03/23 05:10:48 $
* @version $Revision: 1.1.1 $
* @license GNU General Public License, version 2 http://www.opensource.org/licenses/GPL-2.0
**/

namespace AppBundle\Model;

class FloydWarshall {
```

the constructor of FloydWarshall:

```
/**
* Constructor
* @param array $graph Graph matrice.
* @param array $nodenames Node names as an array.
*/

public function __construct($graph, $nodenames='') {

    $this->weights = $graph;
    $this->nodes   = count($this->weights);
    if ( ! empty($nodenames) && $this->nodes == count($nodenames) ) {
        $this->nodenames = $nodenames;
    }
    $this->__floydwarshall();

}
```

Comment: What does the `__construct` method of the `FloydWarshall` class look like? At a guess, it's because the file is not using a PSR-4 compatible filename - it should be called `FloydWarshall.php` instead of `fw.class.php`. However, Symfony should give you some really good error reports that will point you right to the problem - are you using the debug (i.e. dev) environment?

Comment: I'll receive this error on a ajax request so there is no error in browserconsole.... only the described above.

Comment: Turn error reporting on.. `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL)`.. 500 error basically says.. u hav really f*ked up something..

Comment: @Blowski Omg, i guess you just nailed it with that comment ^^

Comment: ahh did I? :O How nice..

Comment: not you. @Blowski did. I changed the name of my class File to `FloydWarshall.php` and this solved it obviously. Add an answere and i'll accapt it Blowski. Thx :) And Sugato, thx to you too. I have my errors on.. still just receive this one :D but as i Sayed, looks like its solved :D

Comment: You should mark @Blowski 's answer as the correct one then!

Comment: @AlvinBunk sure. But its not like im waiting the whole day for someone to post an ansere :D so sometimes I decide to come back next day and see if some happend. Actually I also could delete this post because there were so many hatefull devotes but in the end this post may solve others problems to because the dont know (like i didnt) that the class has to have a well formed name (see answere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, Symfony 3 uses either [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) or [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Assuming that you're using Composer, you configure which one to support in your `composer.json` file.

With PSR-4, your filenames must correspond to your class names, and your directory names must match your namespaces. So if your entity is called `FloydWarshall` in the namespace `AppBundle\Entity`:

- it must be in the directory `src/AppBundle/Entity`
- the file must be called `FloydWarshall.php`

The reason for this strictness is the autoloader which comes with Composer. When you do `new AppBundle\Entity\FloydWarshall`, the autoloader knows where to find the file for that class. In your case, you had named it `fw.class.php` so the autoloader couldn't find it.

---

Tangentially to the question, are you using the `dev` environment? If you are, Symfony will give you a very helpful error message which will help you to diagnose the problem much quicker.